# the process cannot access the file as its being used by another process

Tags: c#

have been struggling with this error for ages. Below is the code is question

```
        for ( Int32 Counter = 0; Counter < x.Rows.Count; Counter++)
        {
            using (FileStream bitmapFile = new FileStream(@"c:/someOlddir/file1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (Bitmap uploadedbitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapFile))
                {
                    using (System.Drawing.Image uploadedbitmapResized = ExtensionHelpers.Resize(uploadedbitmap, 800, 600, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone))
                    {
                        uploadedbitmapResized.Save(@"c:/someNewdir/file1.txt",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                }
            }
           /*errror occurss on this line */
             File.SetCreationTime(@"c:/someNewdir/file1.txt",someDateTimeVariable);

        }
```

The problem I am having with this code is that It works just fine for the first 30 or 40 images in the collection but when i get to 50 or 60 I get an error saying that the file I am trying to set the date-time to is being used by another process. but this error only occurs when I am iterating through a large collection and at the 40 or 50th position in the iteration how can this be that the first 30 images work just fine and then all of  a sudden a file is now locked by a process. I have everything in using statements but this error still persists.

Do I Have to some how wait until the file is saved before accessing it but this shouldn't be the case since i am saving the file first and then trying to access it. what is wrong with code?

Comment: I suspect that it isn't your code that has the file opened. It's probably some other program that just saw your new file and wants to look at it. Anti virus software likes to do this.

Comment: Try to modify the [disk write caching](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259716) and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find this now, but I remember from one of my previous projects that use of `using` in this case doesn't work.

So, drop all of the usings and manage the file closing manually.

Comment: Did as you suggested..... I removed the using statement on the "uploadedbitmapResized" and explicitly called "uploadedbitmapResized.Dispose()" after saving and that did the trick. but isn't Using statement supposed to take  care of that? anywheres thx :)